# How configure connection existence check in C3P0?

Tags: java, jpa, jdbc, connection-pooling, jdbc-odbc

I am using the below code to get `Connection`. I have used the `c3p0` library for connection pooling.

```
package com.dataSource.c3p0;

import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource;

public class DataSource {

    private static DataSource     datasource;
    private ComboPooledDataSource cpds;

    private DataSource() throws IOException, SQLException, PropertyVetoException {
        cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        cpds.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); //loads the jdbc driver
        cpds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test");
        cpds.setUser("root");
        cpds.setPassword("root");

        // the settings below are optional -- c3p0 can work with defaults
        cpds.setMinPoolSize(5);
        cpds.setAcquireIncrement(5);
        cpds.setMaxPoolSize(20);
        cpds.setMaxStatements(180);

    }

    public static DataSource getInstance() throws IOException, SQLException, PropertyVetoException {
        if (datasource == null) {
            datasource = new DataSource();
            return datasource;
        } else {
            return datasource;
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return this.cpds.getConnection();
    }

}
```

Now my question is, this code is not checking whether the connection is existing or not. Most likely this will get hit by the famous connection closed error after 8 hours.

While I was using C3P0 with hibernate, there were configurations to test the connection and re-establish it. The config I did was below

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">3000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">300</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">SELECT 1</property>
```

How can I do the same connection test on checkout here, so I can use it in JDBC too?

Comment: Hi PeakGen, I am facing the same issue which you mentioned about closed connection error, but that happens after a quite long time not after 8 hours. Are there any config settings which I can check for to confirm on that as to me it looks like that only is causing the issue as I have not kept check on connection if its valid or not. Any help is really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a good section on [configuring connection testing](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_connection_testing) in the C3P0 documentation. Also, see the section on [configuration override](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#c3p0_properties), in particular the precedence rules.

(In particular, the advice on using JDBC4 drivers which supports `isValid()` is good.)

In your code, you could simply add

```
cpds.setTestConnectionOnCheckout( true );
cpds.setPreferredTestQuery( "SELECT 1" );
```

to your `DataSource` constructor. Be sure that the query actually talks to the database, I seem to recall some driver implementations that didn't actually go to the DB for certain queries of this kind :-)

Cheers,